# delta hyperbolicity of a product of poincare balls?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

I know how to compute the $\delta$-hyperbolicity of a $2D$ poincaré disk of radius 1, but I was wondering how to generalize such computations to:

1. Higher dimensions
2. Poincaré disk with radius $r$ and conformal factor $\lambda^r_x=1/(1-\Vert x\Vert^2/r^2)$
3. **A cartesian product of several poincaré disks/balls**

The third point is the most important.

Intuitively, I think 1) $\delta$ should be independent of the dimension, 2)  increasing the radius $r$ should increase $\delta$ because it makes the space look more Euclidean, and 3) I have no idea.

Comment: A cartesian product will contain an isometrically embedded Euclidean plane. What do you think this should imply?

Comment: Should this imply that a cartesian product of 2 2D poincaré disks is not $\delta$-hyperbolic for any $\delta$?

Comment: Hi tisydi, welcome to MO. I think I am getting tripped up with your question. Perhaps can sharpen it a little? My confusion stems from the fact, that the Cartesian product of 2 2D Poincare disks is not $\delta$-hyperbolic for any $\delta$ for the comment given above. These questions are good places to start thinking about $\delta$-hyperbolic space, but I fear they do not rise to the research level questions.

Comment: Happily, MathStackExchange is the right forum for asking questions. You might peruse some of those questions to see if you can find a satisfying answer there: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=delta+hyperbolic  as your question stands now, I am voting to migrate to MSE, but I would encourage you to post to MO in the future.